# Sort a nxn matrix (2D Array)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, matrix

During a programming test I was asked to write a Java program to perform sorting on a 3x3 matrix. i.e. I was given a matrix (a 2D array, say `m[3][3]`)

```
2 6 1
3 5 7 
4 8 9
```

I was asked to sort this matrix which should give an output matrix

```
1 2 3  
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

What I did was to convert this 3x3 matrix into a 1D array

```
a[9] = {2,6,1,3,5,7,4,8,9}
```

and performed bubble sort on this array and converted the resultant array back to a 2D array.

I was not satisfied with this approach as I felt this approach is very cheesy. Is there a better way to do this.

**Edit**: I would like to remove the array conversion part. Any sorting algorithm can be used and would like to perform sort on the matrix (2D array) itself.

Comment: Yes, by using a more efficient sort than bubble sort. But it's a strange task as the matrix is absolutely not treated as a matrix.

Comment: For smaller n you can try network sorting also.

Answer (score 7):

Well under your strange requirements you can create a *view* list backed by the input matrix and sort it using the standard `Collections.sort`:

```
public static void sortMatrix(final int[][] matrix) {
    // Assuming the matrix is rectangular
    final int n = matrix.length;
    final int m = matrix[0].length;

    List<Integer> list = new AbstractList<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer set(int index, Integer element) {
            return matrix[index/m][index%m] = element;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer get(int index) {
            return matrix[index/m][index%m];
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return n*m;
        }
    };
    Collections.sort(list);
}
```

Here we just define our own `get` and `set` methods which change the corresponding matrix element. Usage example:

```
int[][] matrix = {{2,6,1},{3,5,7},{4,8,9}};
sortMatrix(matrix);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix));
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Smart usage and implementation of AbstractList. Enjoyed it. However I'd prefer the pure implementation of the algorithm.

Comment: `List.set()` must return "the element previously at the specified position". See [List.set(int, E)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#set(int,E))

Answer (score 2):

For less time complexity you could use an other sorting algorithm, like quicksort or maybe radixsort (because you only deal with numbers).

Converting the matrix into an array isn't your major time consumption method, but the sorting is. So optimizing that and only afterwards try different methods.

**edit:**

According to your data layout `m[3][3]`, you could use [bucket sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) (this could lead to a greater performance gain, if you use `m[1000][1000]`. Because you already have buckets which you can sort, this will remove the necessity to convert it first.

Comment: see my edit. I would like to remove the array conversion part. Can I do this  sorting on the matrix itself. That is my concern

Comment: @geo What kind of data structure do you have the matrix in?

Comment: I hope this helps. Don't get to worried about performance, when you are sorting a 3x3 matrix. If you deal with very large matrix, this will be necessary

Comment: @cookiesoft  performance is not my worry..I would like to know how can i implement this sorting technique on the 2d array itself not on the 1d array

Answer (score 2):

```
public int[][]  sortMatrix(int matrix[][], int r, int c) {

    for (int k = 0; k < r * c; k++) {
        Integer current = null;
        Integer previous = null;
        Integer currentI = null;
        Integer currentJ = null;
        Integer previousI = null;
        Integer previousJ = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                current = matrix[i][j];
                currentI = i;
                currentJ = j;
                if (previous != null) {
                    if (current < previous) {
                        matrix[currentI][currentJ] = previous;
                        matrix[previousI][previousJ] = current;
                    }
                }
                previous = matrix[i][j];
                previousI = i;
                previousJ = j;
            }
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have N integers, converting it from 2D array -> 1D array and 1D -> 2D array cannot take longer than O(N) time when sorting in general takes more time than that which means Sorting dominates your time complexity. That said, you should focus on implementing more efficient sorting.

Try using heap sort for instance of which time complexity is O(NlogN), which is way faster than bubble sort(O(N^2)). As your input grows larger, you'll see dramatic difference in the amount of time your process takes.

Answer (score 1):

You could take advantage of `Streams`:

```
public int[][] sortWithStreams(int[][] matrix) {
    return Arrays.stream(matrix)
            // Turn it into a stream of ints by streaming each row.
            .flatMapToInt(x -> Arrays.stream(x))
            // Sort it.
            .sorted()
            // Gather the now sorted stream back into a new array.
            .collect(
                    // A new matrix.
                    () -> new int[matrix.length][matrix[0].length],
                    // Consumer folds each value into the next position in an array.
                    new ObjIntConsumer<int[][]>() {
                        // Start at [0][0]
                        int x = 0, y = 0;

                        @Override
                        public void accept(int[][] t, int value) {
                            // Place it and step on.
                            t[y][x++] = value;
                            // Wrap if necessary.
                            if (x >= t[y].length) {
                                x = 0;
                                y += 1;
                            }
                        }

                    },
                    // As `sorted` cannot generate a parallel stream it is safe to ignore the combiner.
                    null);
}

public void test() {
    int[][] matrix1 = {{2, 6, 1}, {3, 5, 7}, {4, 8, 9}};
    int[][] matrix2 = {{2, 6, 1, 12}, {3, 5, 7, 10}, {4, 8, 9, 11}};
    int[][] matrix3 = {{2, 6, 1}, {3, 5, 7}, {4, 8, 9}, {1, 3, 12}};
    // Print them.
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(sortWithStreams(matrix1)));
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(sortWithStreams(matrix2)));
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(sortWithStreams(matrix3)));//
}
```